# Get text from website with VBA

Tags: html, vba, internet-explorer, dom, web-scraping

I Need to create a VBA Macro which takes a specific Website and search for the ID. When the ID is found I Need to take the text and copy it into Excel.

Here is the source code of the Webiste:

```
<tr>
<td style="width: 10%; color: blue" valign="top"><a name="111" id="111">111</td>
<td><pre>  
    Some text I Need in excel
</pre></a><td>
</tr>
```

I Need the text between "pre"

This is my try in VBA:

```
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = True
IE.Navigate  Website_URL

Do While IE.Busy And Not IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
  DoEvents
Loop
Set Document = IE.Document

Dim SearchValue As String  
Set Element = Document.getElementById(SearchValue).getAttribute("pre")

Range("I1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = Element
```

I also tried instead of ".getAttribute" other methods and also tried to use Element As an String but it also didn't work.

It would be awesome if someone could help me with my Code :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text is not located in attribute but in `pre` element. So `getAttribute` function can't return the desired text.

Have a look at function `querySelector` if you want to get the first text. This function returns `IHTMLElement` and accepts [selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssreF/css_selectors.asp).

If you wish to return all texts then try function `querySelectorAll`. This function returns `IHTMLDOMChildrenCollection`and accepts [selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssreF/css_selectors.asp) as well. HTH

---

*Example:*

```
' Add reference to Microsoft Internet Controls (SHDocVw)
' Add reference to Microsoft HTML Object Library

Dim selector As String
' select element with id = SearchValue which has td which has pre
selector = "#" & SearchValue & " td pre" 

Dim onePre As IHTMLElement
Set onePre = doc.querySelector(selector)
If Not onePre Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "First pre element text: " & onePre.innerText
End If

Dim allPre As IHTMLDOMChildrenCollection
Set allPre = doc.querySelectorAll(selector)

If allPre.Length > 0 Then
    Dim el, text
    For el = 0 To allPre.Length - 1
        text = text & allPre.Item(el).innerText
    Next
    MsgBox "All pre elements text: " & text
End If

ie.Quit
```